# How to restore VB Project after Stash

Tags: vb.net, git-stash

I have had a few clicks exploring some Visual Studio features and other tools. But I got myself into trouble after clicking on Stash. I clicked on stash and lost my VB.Net project I was still working on. In the directory I can not find it. How do I recovery the project.

Comment: I take it you are referring to [The Git Stash Functionality in Visual Studio 2019](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019/) so I added a tag for that. If that isn't what you meant, please delete that tag.

Comment: https://dev.to/meduzen/recover-a-lost-git-stash-in-two-steps-569 Don't know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMorton and K.Madden. Firstly I dont understand what Stash or Git Stash is. I am trying hard to understand but I cant understand it for now, maybe at this point.  What I want to achieve is to get my Project folder in repos with its contents and continue my project. Maybe I can do this Stash thing later. The above links kind of confused me a bit.